# Compiling *.vhdl into a library, using Altera Quartus II

Tags: floating-point, vhdl, fixed-point, intel-fpga, quartus

I am trying to use 'Floating point and Fixed point package' as a part of my filter design in VHDL. I am using Altera Quartus II as the development environment. I downloaded the file package from the website: http://www.vhdl.org/fphdl/, now available at http://web.archive.org/web/20160305202256/http://www.vhdl.org/fphdl/

In their user guide, below is mentioned:

```
'fixed_float_types_c.vhdl', 'fixed_pkg_c.vhdl' and 'float_pkg_c.vhdl'
should be compiled into a library called "ieee_proposed".
```

However, I do not exactly know how I can compile the mentioned *.vhdl files into a library using Altera Quartus II tool.

Any tip would be appreciated.

Comment: The lines I included above are directly from their user guide, so yes.

Comment: Ah, yes, but it does not compile as a regular project, because it doesn't have regular VHDL syntax, such as 'missing entity' and etc...

Comment: It is a good idea, but how can I include those files without using "use <library_name>.all;" something like that? I don't know how... ;(

Comment: um. It didn't work out either ... Or I should ask 'how can I add those files to current working library?'

Comment: Oh, adding a line 'library work;' before the 'use work.<package>.all' allowed me to compile them without error. Now, I need to test, if I can actually use the library functions. Thank you! :)

Comment: I've deleted my comments, since they're all reflected in the answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Altera Quartus II GUI you can add the 'fixed_float_types_c.vhdl',
'fixed_pkg_c.vhdl' and 'float_pkg_c.vhdl' files to the project through the
"Project Navigator" tab called "Files".  See figure below.

[image]

When you add the files you can specify the target library under "Properties".
See figure below.

[image]

You can also modify the Quartus II settings (".qsf") file for the project, and
add the lines:

```
set_global_assignment -name VHDL_FILE fixed_float_types_c.vhdl -library ieee_proposed
set_global_assignment -name VHDL_FILE fixed_pkg_c.vhdl -library ieee_proposed
set_global_assignment -name VHDL_FILE float_pkg_c.vhdl -library ieee_proposed
```

However, you may want to determine if compiling into the "ieee_proposed" library is required, and otherwise you can just compile them into the "work" library with other files.

Answer (score 0):

Just compile them into `work` as you would any other files in your project and refer to them by `use work._library_name_`.