# to_float() and dividing errors

Tags: compiler-errors, floating-point, vhdl

After bringing this issue up in a comment ([compiler errors when compiling *.vhdl into a library - Altera Quartus II](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697541/compiler-errors-when-compiling-vhdl-into-a-library-altera-quartus-ii)) I decided that it would probably be better off as a separate question.

This is the code excerpt, the main part of a process:

```
    variable denum : integer; 
    variable num : integer; 
    variable dividend : float (4 downto -27);  

begin
    dividend := to_float(num) / to_float(denum); 
    ...
```

After being pointed to the error that the to_float() function needs additional arguments, I tried the suggested improvements, but still got some errors:

```
dividend := to_float(num, dividend) / to_float(denum, dividend);
```

returns: "VHDL syntax error at float_pkg_c.vhdl(3843): right bound of range must be a constant"

and

```
dividend := to_float(num, 4, -27) / to_float(denum, 4, -27);
```

returns: "VHDL error at SM.vhd(93): value "-27" is outside the target constraint range (0 to 2147483647)"

The error messages point that the problem originates in the wrong call of to_float, but I can't see any problem in the method, considering the fact that it is part of the latest package. Can someone clarify that to me? Also I'm not sure whether the divide operation can be executed in this way, I mean in one line, returning a float obtained from the particular ints.

Comment: what does your include for float pkg look like?

Comment: I generated the include files, at least it said it was successful. What is the extension of the include file? I'm not sure where it was generated.

Comment: I just meant the lines that start with 'use'...

Comment: If you go to http://www.vhdl.org/fphdl/ you will see specific packages for different tools including Altera : some tools still don't synthesise everything in the standard proper, possibly including negative indices.

Comment: use ieee_proposed.float_pkg.all;
@BrianDrummond is there any workaround then? I mean, I simply want to divide two integers into a float. I used the materials from the site you provided, are there any details regarding your comment implied? I've gone through the readme file and the comments of the .vhdl file, but found no such limitations.

Comment: It's not clear from either question if you are using the standard package or the Altera-specific version. If you're already using the Altera-specific version I'm sorry I can't be of further help.

Comment: what version of vhdl are you using? I think ieee_proposed should probably be replaced by ieee (depending on your vhdl version)

Comment: I tried it with the Altera specific version, although the "generic" one is newer, with the same results. I even tried substituting the negative index with a positive one, but then it seems to require a round_type type parameter.
ieee_proposed is suggested in the documentation and used from within the files. I'm using Altera Quartus II 7.2.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a problem right here:

```
dividend := to_float(num, 4, -27) / to_float(denum, 4, -27);
```

If you take a look at the definition:

```
-- to_float (Integer)
function to_float (
    arg                     : INTEGER;
    constant exponent_width : NATURAL    := float_exponent_width;  -- length of FP output exponent
    constant fraction_width : NATURAL    := float_fraction_width;  -- length of FP output fraction
    constant round_style    : round_type := float_round_style)  -- rounding option
    return UNRESOLVED_float is
    variable result     : UNRESOLVED_float (exponent_width downto -fraction_width);
    ...
```

Take a look at *fraction_width*: it's a natural. This is the error you're currently getting, as you supply *-27*.

When you look farther down in the implementation a little, *result* uses the inverse of *fraction_width*. Hence, you should be invoking

```
to_float(num, 4, 27)
```

Comment: I tried that, the following error output was reported
Error (10454): VHDL syntax error at float_pkg_c.vhdl(3840): right bound of range must be a constant
Error (10657): VHDL Subprogram error at SM.vhd(93):  failed to elaborate call to subprogram "to_float"
Error (10346): VHDL error at float_pkg_c.vhdl(4843): formal port or parameter "l" must have actual or default value
Error (10346): VHDL error at float_pkg_c.vhdl(4843): formal port or parameter "r" must have actual or default value
Error (10658): VHDL Operator error at SM.vhd(93): failed to evaluate call to operator ""/""

Comment: Are you sure you're trying this out like I typed above? All these error messages are related to fraction_width not being constant.
Are you maybe not showing us your real code but some implementation of it? If this is identical to the code you're trying, then I'm at a loss, too. In that case, you should probably investigate your float_pkg_c.vhdl and Quartus settings.