# How to use sin, arcsin functions in vhdl Quatus 2 16.1 Lite?

Tags: floating-point, vhdl, intel-fpga

I am using Quatus 2 Prime 16.1 Lite version.
what i am trying to do as follows, 
I have compiled **float_pkg_c,fixed_pkg_c** under **ieee_proposed** library as in shown in below link in comment. and i am using **to_float** to convert real variable to std logic vector as follows,

```
phi_c <= to_std_logic_vector( to_float(phi_c_F, float32'high, -float32'low) );
```

below phi_c_F is a variable which is to be calculated using sin, arcsin of math_real library.and i found operators in math_real non-synthesize, and i want there xx.dddddddd **at least 10 decimal points**. 
then, phi_c is send via Avalon memory mapping (32bits std logic vector) to HPS system.

in below code **pre_digital,rp are integers** and are signals which calculates in another process.

```
library ieee;
library ieee_proposed;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.math_real.all;
use ieee.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use ieee.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use ieee_proposed.float_pkg.ALL;
use ieee_proposed.fixed_pkg.ALL;
use ieee_proposed.fixed_float_types.ALL;
```

inside architecture,

```
PROCESS(clk_50,start_cal)
variable Pr_F,rp_rad_s_F,F_c_F,ph_c_F,t_p_F,l_c_F,r_c_F,Ar_F,pre_R ,r_s: float (4 downto -27); 
BEGIN
--r_s := 8.98;
--r_c_F := 3.44;
--l_c_F := 5.67;
IF rising_edge(clk_50)  AND start_cal ='1'  THEN

pre_R           := to_float(pre_digital,4 ,27) ;       
Pr_F            := 3.3 * (pre_R / 65535.0);    
rpm_rad_s_F     := to_float(rp,4 ,27) * (2.0 * MATH_PI / 60.0);
Ar_F            := MATH_PI*r_s*r_s;
F_c_F           := Pr_F * Ar_F;             
ph_c_F          := arcsin((r_c_F / l_c_F) * sin(rp_rad_s_F *  to_float(t,4 ,27)));

ph_c_F_vctr  <= to_std_logic_vector(ph_c_F);
END IF;
END PROCESS;
```

when compiling soc.system i get error,

> Error (10511): VHDL Qualified Expression error at test_pipe.vhd(136):
>   ARCSIN type specified in Qualified Expression must match
>   UNRESOLVED_float type that is implied for expression by context

Comment: [Does the Quartus Prime software support IEEE fixed_pkg and float_pkg libraries in VHDL-2008?](https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/solutions/rd09062016_335.html) It also begs  the question as to why you are trying to include floating point in a UART.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580207/compiling-vhdl-into-a-library-using-altera-quartus-ii this link shows everything that i needed thank you

Comment: @user1155120 then the method in above link will not let me do calculations with floating numbers in Quartus 16.1 Lite version ? I need to use floating numbers with sin, cos in math_real library.

Comment: Please explain your problem: what do you want to achieve? Why do you need floating point arithmetic and in what way? Show some code maybe. Floating point in FPGA is a very big challenge and a very inefficient use of resources. Why are you using an FPGA for this?

Comment: @JHBonarius i have added the vdhl code that I need to run on soc-fpga

Comment: I was just looking back at your edits. Please don't radically change/edit your question each time. My a new question for each new question.

Comment: And why are you using `std_logic_arith`? It is a bad package. You should only use `numeric_std`.

Comment: I have to agree with @JHBonarius - you seem to be attempting something that is very hard, when this line of code - `IF rising_edge(clk_50)  AND start_cal ='1'  THEN` - suggests you are a beginner. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I need to implement this on hardware level (VHDL) for my project.

Comment: Do you really need floating point? I have been designing digital hardware for receiving radio signals on and off for 28 years. There is quite a big dynamic range requirement - many 10s of dB, yet I have never needed floating point. Could you use fixed point?

Comment: @Matthew Taylor yes i can use fixed point. I cannot drop all decimal points. I found arcsin in ALTERA_FP_FUNCTIONS IP core. this can be used here?right?

Comment: I don't know. I have never used Altera IP.

Comment: From what I can see, ALTERA_FP_FUNCTIONS is for Arria 10, whilst your board has a Cyclone 5 on it.

Comment: @Matthew Taylor then there is no other way to get arcsin? instead of making cordic ip or a lookup table for arcsin

Comment: Of course it is possible. It is just very complex. People get paid big bucks to design that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your code and requirements, it seems you are not aware of the capabilities of an FPGA. An FPGA consist of a collection of programmable logic lookup tables, combined with some hardwired multipliers. Except for the newest generation Altera (Stratix 10 e.g.), these multipliers are *fixed-point only* and would require extra logic in the LUTs to realize floating-point kind of operations. Also, the multipliers only offer limited precision: ~18 bit.

You seem to want full floating point precision (64 bit) and perform very complex operations, as division and trigonometric functions (sin/arcsin). A lot of logic is required to realize these functions. Trigonometric functions are not even implemented in the `float_pkg` library. You will probably have to use a CORDIC-like component to realize such a function.

But just think about what you seem to want to achieve in your code:

- 2 * floating-point division
- 8 * floating-point multiplication
- 1 * sin()
- 1 * arcsin()

All *within one clock cycle!* `clk_50` seems to indicate 50 MHz... That's not going to work. You need to pipeline it properly.

What you want to realize on your FPGA is advanced stuff. You really need to know what you are doing. Please start simple, by flashing a LED or something.

Likely you should just run this code on a general purpose processor and not use an FPGA...

Comment: Yes I am new to perform this type of mathematical functions on fpga. Is there any standard sin, cos, tan lookup table for Altera that can be used in De0 nano Soc board? and what is CORDIC component? can you show a link here for CORDIC vhdl file.

Comment: I have never done sin arcsin functions in VHDL, so this is hard for me, if you can direct me to a source i will manage myself.

Comment: @iopertyki please do some research yourself. just Google "CORDIC" for instance. This is very complex hardware design; it cannot be explained by a simple link.

Comment: is this  same for the verilog?

Comment: @iopertyki what do you think the difference between verilog and VHDL is? You should really do some research yourself before asking questions.

Comment: ALTERA_FP_FUNCTIONS IP core can be used in my work isn't it? it has arcsin,  arccos

Comment: I only see sine, cosine and arctangent in the IP user guide. But anyhow, why are you asking this? I don't know if you can use it. I don't know what your requirements are, nor your capabilities as a designer.