# How to calculate sin inverse (arcsin) in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, lookup-tables, intel-fpga, inverse, cordic

I am using **Altera De0 nano Soc FPGA**, and **Quartus 16.1 lite edition**. After doing a search on internet, I found that to get `sin`, `cos` and `atan` Altera's CORDIC IP core can be used directly. And also found lookup table (LUT) can be used for sin or cos (mostly available in google) but how to get **`sin` inverse (`ARCSIN`) in `VHDL`?**
I have found a `sin` and `cos` lookup table, is there a way to generate **`sin` inverse**?

Comment: can anybody give me a hint at least? just not giving negative points?because i am stuck here if someone who read this and give me hint it will be helpful me to continue my project task, I am new to fpga vhdl functions that uses arcsin, cosine in calculations .

Comment: Is this a homework assignment or so? Somebody asked about the same question 2 days ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44762660/how-to-use-sin-arcsin-functions-in-vhdl-quatus-2-16-1-lite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to generate a lookup table for `arcsin`.

**1)** Determine the input precision, in other words how many values you want to keep in your lookup table. For example, you need to store 11 values if your precision is 0.1.

```
arcsin(0), arcsin(0.1), arcsin(0.2), ..., arcsin(1).
```

**2)** Find the results of arcsin functions. [Here](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/trigonometry-calculators/arc-sine-calculator.php) is a source I found by googling.

```
arcsin(0)   = 0
arcsin(0.1) = 5.7
arcsin(0.2) = 11.5
...
arcsin(1)   = 90
```

**3)** Determine the output precision.

If the precision is 1, all values are rounded to integers.

```
arcsin(0.1) = 6
arcsin(0.2) = 12
```

If the precision is 0.5, the results are as below. The output needs 9-bit size for this precision. 8 bits are for the integer part and 1 bit is for the fractional part.

```
arcsin(0.1) = 5.5
arcsin(0.2) = 11.5
```

**4)** Map input values to addresses of the lookup table. For example, it should be like below for 0.1 precision. This example doesn't require an additional lookup table or big logic for address mapping.

```
0   -> 0
0.1 -> 1
0.2 -> 2
...
1   -> 10
```

**5)** Implement this lookup table in VHDL like the ones you've found for `sin` or `cos`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

For instance using CORDIC...One of my first hits on Google:
[A survey of CORDIC algorithms for FPGA based computer](http://www.andraka.com/files/crdcsrvy.pdf)

Comment: CORDIC seems hard, do you know where to find a better lookup table, a vhdl file?

Comment: @komto909 What you want to achieve is very difficult. You should either go all the way (learn about cordic, evaluate different implementations, etc) or not go at all (choose another approach, e.g. CPU)...